# Order and timing for promises in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I don't understand the concept of promises in AngularJS. I have two functions: one to get a distant setup configuration, and other one to fetch this distant configuration (stored in `$scope`). I need to separate them because I use different timeouts or calls for each one in other parts of application.

I thought that with the promises everything was running one by one, and here I discover that my function fetch starts before the loading function. Why? Why a system is waiting to download my setup, and then starts the fetch?

```
    /* ----- $scope.sea.funcs.seaInit(); ----- */
    $scope.sea.funcs.seaInit = function() {
        // PROMISES ORDER
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;
        // 0 : get distant config
        promise.then(function() {
            /* ----- SERVICE ConfigService.generale(); ----- */
            ConfigService.generale({call: 'yes'}, function(responseSC) {
                // store datas
                $scope.datas.shared.configuration = responseSC[0];
                console.log('load end');
            });
        });
        // 1 : fetch stored distant config
        promise.then(function() {
            $scope.sea.funcs.seaConfigFetch();
        });
        // final resolve
        deferred.resolve('ok');
    }

    /* ----- $scope.sea.funcs.seaConfigFetch(); ----- */
    $scope.sea.funcs.seaConfigFetch = function() {
            console.log('fetch start');
            // here i do operations with $scope ...
   }

    /* ----- $scope.sea.funcs.seaInit(); call ----- */
    $timeout($scope.sea.funcs.seaInit, 3000);
```

Here, 'fetch start' appears before 'load end'. I put service directly in first promise because I thinked that is the problem but no.

I have errors 'not defined' for `$scope` values.

Comment: I would watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o84ryzNp36Q   Your understanding of promises isn't quite right, which is why your example isn't working the way you would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what you have above, you're defining 1 promise and attaching two functions to be called when it is resolved, I think what you want is for the call to seaConfigFetch to occur after ConfigServices.generale has completed. To do that, you can update to the following:

```
/* ----- $scope.sea.funcs.seaInit(); ----- */
$scope.sea.funcs.seaInit = function() {

    // PROMISES ORDER
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;
    // 0 : get distant config
    /* ----- SERVICE ConfigService.generale(); ----- */
    ConfigService.generale({call: 'yes'}, function(responseSC) {
        // store datas
        $scope.datas.shared.configuration = responseSC[0];
        console.log('load end');
        // final resolve
        deferred.resolve('ok');
    });
    // 1 : fetch stored distant config
    promise.then(function() {
        $scope.sea.funcs.seaConfigFetch();
    });
}
```

If ConfigService.generale is returning a promise, you could simplify it more to remove the $q.defer() you create. Or remove the promise entirely and call seaConfigFetch where you have deferred.resolve. Here's a good article on common anti-patterns with promises: http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/